# I cant reach a method (Images)

Tags: c#, class, methods, subclass

I'm creating a game in order to learn C# programming.

I have a class called `Unit` and two derived types, `Wolf` and `Spider`.

I've also created a class called `UnitList` that contains a `List<Unit>` where I would like to store my `Unit` instances.

There is also another class called `Battle` where a method loops through each `Unit` in my `List<Unit>`. I would like to use a different method based on the `Type` of `Unit`, be it a `Wolf` or a `Spider`.

Please see the image below as I am not good at explaining concepts; I have been stuck on this for days.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is the c# `is` operator.

For example

```
if(unit is Wolf)
{
    // Do something
}
else if (unit is Spider)
{
    // Do Something
}
```

[C# is operator on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx)

Once you are in those blocks, you can use a type cast to call your methods.

```
if(unit is Wolf)
{
    ((Wolf)unit).WolfAttack();
}
```

However, there is a much cleaner way of doing this in C# using the inheritance tree you have already set up.

```
class Unit
{
    public virtual void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unit attacks!");
    }
}

class Wolf : Unit
{
    public override void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wolf attacks!");
    }
}

class Spider : Unit
{
    public override void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Spider attacks!");
    }
}
```

By marking the method on `Unit` as `virtual` you can override its behavior on classes that inherit from `Unit`. Thus your code to call the attack now just becomes

```
foreach(Unit unit in team1.GetList())
{
    unit.Attack();
}
```

as it will call the proper `Attack()` function for each `Unit` be it a `Spider` or a `Wolf`.

There is also an alternative to this, and that is to use Interfaces. If there is no shared implementation between the `Spider` and `Wolf` class, this is often a good way to go rather than using `abstract` classes.

You would define an `IUnit` interface, for example

```
public IUnit
{
    int Health { get; set; }
    void Attack();
}
```

Then instead of inheriting from `Unit` you would implement `IUnit` instead.

```
class Wolf : IUnit
{
    public int Health { get; set; }

    public void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wolf attacks!");
    }
}

class Spider : IUnit
{
    public int Health { get; set; }

    public void Attack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Spider attacks!");
    }
}
```

You would then use `IUnit` in place of `Unit`.

Both methods are valid, and both have advantages and disadvantages. Classes are allowed to implement many interfaces, but only inherit one class. Interfaces can not define functionality, so they can't completely replace inheritance. There are more, but that is the most basic difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to compare a `System.Type` with an `instance`. What you're looking to do is use the `typeof` operator or the `is/as` construct for C#. Rather, for a better solution, you could use inheritance.

You're Unit class could be declared abstract as such:

```
abstract class Unit
{
    private int health;
    private int damage;

    protected Unit()
    {
        health = 100;
    }

    public abstract void Attack();
}
```

While your Wolf class could be:

```
class Wolf : Unit
{
    public override void Attack()
    {
        // Do Something...
    }
}
```

And you could then retrieve each `Unit` instance from your list and call `Unit.Attack();` and it would call the respective `Attack()`.